# Is changing replication factor on an existing topic safe

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a situation where certain topics for one of our applications were created with RF=1 which causes problems when there is maintenance on the brokers and the brokers are shutdown temporarily one by one. Our setup contains a small Kafka cluster with 3 nodes.

Ideally, we would like to increase the RF to 3, and set the minimum in-sync replicas to 2 for these topics which should allow us to tolerate 1 broker downtime and we have verified this successfully in our development environment, and I can't find any documentation that would suggest that this operation is unsafe.

I know that it is possible to change the replication factor of existing topics using the Kafka cli tools (for example by using `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` or using UI (for example, `Kafka UI` or `Confluent Control Center`) but my question is:

Is it a safe operation to **increase** the replication factor on an existing topic? And what exactly happens to the topic when the RF changes and there are existing consumers, existing producers and existing messages?

Many thanks

Comment: I've done it before, and didn't observe any significant problem (with active clients). I'm sure there was extra load on the brokers while it was replicating. If there's a chance a broker could fail over during replicating, that's where it's unsafe overall